# Live Location Tracking in React Native with Expo

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, react-native

Thanks in-advance. I am very new to React.

I'm trying to build an android application with React Native (Expo), PHP and MySQL, which requires live location tracking of salesmen for Admin to monitor.

Can any one please suggest me any idea on Live Location Tracking, even when the salesman's mobile screen is off/screen is locked with application running in background.

Salesman don't need any map component as they have nothing to do with their location. Just a Background Task sending their location details for the Admin, where he can track all his salesman's movement (for whole day) on their field job.

Only one application for both(Admin & Salesman), with dynamic menu based on user type which hides menu items for salesman login.

1. What is the standard method/process for this job ?
2. Is their any tutorial which i can follow ?

Any extra suggestions/points which i might be missing.

I have searched the whole internet for few days and i am having difficulty understanding the Expo documentation with very less example. Didn't found any suitable solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found a solution for my problem, sharing it for anybody who is stuck with the same problem.

Get Users Live Location (every step he takes) with React Native.

Thanks

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = "background-location-task";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      region: null,
      error: '',
    };
  }

  _getLocationAsync = async () => {
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      distanceInterval: 1,
      timeInterval: 5000
    });
    // watchPositionAsync Return Lat & Long on Position Change
    this.location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        distanceInterval: 1,
        timeInterval: 10000
      },
      newLocation => {
        let { coords } = newLocation;
        // console.log(coords);
        let region = {
          latitude: coords.latitude,
          longitude: coords.longitude,
          latitudeDelta: 0.045,
          longitudeDelta: 0.045
        };
        this.setState({ region: region });
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    return this.location;
  };

  async componentWillMount() {
    // Asking for device location permission
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

    if (status === "granted") {
      this._getLocationAsync();
    } else {
      this.setState({ error: "Locations services needed" });
    }
    userId = (await AsyncStorage.getItem("userId")) || "none";
    userName = (await AsyncStorage.getItem("userName")) || "none";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          showsCompass={true}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          rotateEnabled={true}
          ref={map => {
            this.map = map;
          }}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    let lat = locations[0].coords.latitude;
    let long = locations[0].coords.longitude;
    userId = (await AsyncStorage.getItem("userId")) || "none";

    // Storing Received Lat & Long to DB by logged In User Id
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://000.000.0.000/phpServer/ajax.php",
      data: {
        action: "saveLocation",
        userId: userId,
        lat,
        long
      }
    });
    // console.log("Received new locations for user = ", userId, locations);
  }
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  }
});
```

Comment: That will drain their battery quite quickly. in reality you only need location updates every 60 seconds or even every 5 minutes. Not every 5 or 10 seconds

Comment: It is just a working demo. Increase the "timeInterval" value (inside _getLocationAsync(); ) to what ever suites you best, the TaskManager / Axios will fire after the specified time interval.